# Eclipse IDE - Добавление .jar файла как src

Tags: java, eclipse

Всем привет, в общем, у меня появилась проблемка. У меня есть .jar файл, в котором есть пекеджи и классы. И мне надо перенести всё что есть в этом .jar файле в мой java проект, то есть что бы я мог их изменять, etc... Всё это я делаю в среде разработки Eclipse IDE. Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: если вы хотите забрать исходный код, то это возможно любым декомпилятором. но все дело в том, что в джаве практически всегда исходный код находится в открытом доступе, посему ничего декомпилировать не нужно, можно просто взять код. последний вариант лучше, поскольку в декомпилированном коде может быть ряд проблем (к примеру, именование переменных, методов, классов) и т.д. да и компилированный код не всегда идентичен исходному. а что это за .jar, это какая-то библиотека?

Comment: @Дмитрий нет, это не библеотека. Просто я со знакомым делаю что то типа "проекта", и что-то делает он, а что-то я. И просто переписывать код не очень удобно. Вот и спрашиваю, можно ли просто .jar перекинуть в Eclipse

Comment: @Дмитрий я кстати только что вспомнил, мне кто-то говорил вроде что можно добавить .jar через Build Path. Только вот не помню кто говорил, и как это делается :). В общем, можно ли как то добавить через 'Build Path' ?

Comment: вы можете добавит jar в свой проект и указать maven, gradle, ant (не знаю, что у вас) , что этот файл является зависимостью, но в этом случае менять его исходный код нельзя (можно только просмотреть)

Comment: а вообще, если вы вместе работаете над проектом, то есть гит, кде хранится весь код. а чтобы организовать взаимодействие между вашими компонентами, просто напишите интерфейсы и всех делов

Comment: huh, хорошо, спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: не за что, удачи в разработке